# Find Type of Sql Query

Tags: asp.net, mysql, c#-4.0, ado.net

This is `console` which is communicating with `MySQL` Database and returning the `Resultset`, but in this i am not able to find the type of query . so i have to ask end user select appropriate the **Query type**(*Drop Down Selection*) before executing the Query.

is there there any way to find out nature of query so i can choose execute `non-query` or `Data adapter` to return the values.

[image: My-Sql Editor]